# Problem installing Team Foundation Server Extensions for Windows SharePoint Services

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, team-foundation-server

I have an existing TFS 2010 (single tier) box, currently configured to use a local WSS instance.  However, we want to change the SharePoint integration and point to an existing MOSS 2010 instance on a different server.

I've installed Team Foundation Server Extensions for Windows SharePoint Services on the MOSS 2010 box, but when I go to configure the Extensions, I'm getting the following error in the log file:

> "!Verify Error!: TF250002: No content
>   Web applications exist in this Web
>   farm. You must create a new SharePoint
>   Web application in SharePoint Central
>   Administration."

I'm a member of the farm administrator's group, also I'm a local Administrator.  There are three existing Web Applications according to SharePoint Central Administration.

At the moment, I'm checking whether any of the existing web applications support "the settings that Team Foundation Server requires" (which is a bit ambiguous).  There's heaps of documentation on how to *create* a new web application, but scare info on how to edit an existing one.

Any ideas what the block might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's rather uncool to ask and answer your own question.. however.. I finally got to the bottom of the issue.  I'd assumed that local Administrators were also sysadmin in the SQL Server instance - turns out that was an incorrect assumption.

The account I was installing from did not have permissions to access the SharePoint Configuration table, which is why this was failing.  Adding the appropriate setting in User Mapping and the installation worked fine.